# Basis of the space of homogeneous polynomials clarification

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

I want to prove the following proposition.

> Let $H(n,m)$ denote the vector space of homogeneous polynomials of degree $m$ in $n$ variables over $\mathbb{C}$. Then here exist a finite number of vectors $a_j = (a_1^j,\dots,a_n^j)$, such that the elements of the form $$(a_j\cdot z)^m = (a_1^jz_1+\cdots+a_n^jz_n)^m,$$ span the space $H(n,m)$. Moreover, we can choose this vectors to be in any open subset of $\mathbb{C}^n$.

I came across the following proof (in some course notes):

Assume the contrary. Then the set $A = \{(a\cdot z)^m|\;a\in\mathbb{C}^m\}$ forms a linear subspace of $H(n,m)$. Thus $A$ is a kernel of some linear form on $H(n,m)$. We express this linear form with respect to the basis $\{z^{\alpha}|\;|\alpha| = m\}$ (using multiindex notation). Then we have a non zero vector $c_\alpha$ such that $$\sum_{\alpha} c_\alpha a^\alpha = 0 \quad\forall a\in\mathbb{C}^n.$$ Since $\{a^\alpha\}$ is a basis we get a contradiction.

I have some trouble with understanding the last step in the proof. What exactly does guarantee such $c_\alpha$? Is this conclusion even correct? Furthermore, if it is, what would be the argument that taking vectors $a$ form any open subset of $\mathbb{C}^n$ would be sufficient?

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: I am having trouble with the definition of your proposed basis. How are the vectors $a=(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ in your second paragraph defined?

Comment: The claim as I understand it is, that for any open set in $U \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ we can find a suitable number of vectors $a_j = (a_1^j,\dots,a_n^j)$, $a_j\in U$, such that the set $a_j\cdot z$ forms a basis for $H(n,m)$ (where $\cdot$ denotes a regular (not hermitian) scalar product).

Comment: Equivalent formulation I think is that there exist suitable complex linear forms $l_j:\mathbb{C}^n\to\mathbb{C}$, such that the set $\{l_j(z)^m\}$ forms a basis. (In the previous comment the element $a_j\cdot z$ should be raised to the $m$-th power)